# Delphi FMX initialize listview

Tags: listview, delphi

I have a FMX App that has listviews on different pages of a tabcontrol. When switching tabs I dynamically fill and format the list entries e.g. by changing the vertical placement. When a listview is shown at the first time the items are shown at the wrong position.
Happens the same on Windows or Android with Delphi versions Seattle and Sydney.

My question is: Is there anything that I can (or have to) do to initialize the listview after adding the items?

To reproduce my problem, you can create a new 'FMX Header/Footer with navigation' application. On the second tab add a client aligned listview an add the following code in the tabcontrol onchange handler:

```
procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  it: TListViewItem;
begin
  if TabControl1.ActiveTab = TabItem2 then
  begin
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      it := ListView1.Items.Add;
      it.Text := inttostr(i);
      if odd(i) then
        it.Objects.TextObject.PlaceOffset.Y := 0
      else
        it.Objects.TextObject.PlaceOffset.Y := 10;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When running the App and pressing the Next-Button in the header, the list is drawn for the first time with the listviews text shown all aligned in the same way. When switching back and forth the two pages of the tabcontrol, the list is drawn correctly (means like formatted with placeoffset) the second time.

The full listings of the relevant files are:

Main program (dpr):

```
program HeaderFooterNavigation;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation in 'HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation.pas' {HeaderFooterwithNavigation};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(THeaderFooterwithNavigation, HeaderFooterwithNavigation);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Main form unit (pas):

```
unit HeaderFooterFormwithNavigation;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.TabControl,
  System.Actions, FMX.ActnList,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ListView.Types,
  FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, FMX.ListView;

type
  THeaderFooterwithNavigation = class(TForm)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    PreviousTabAction1: TPreviousTabAction;
    TitleAction: TControlAction;
    NextTabAction1: TNextTabAction;
    TopToolBar: TToolBar;
    btnBack: TSpeedButton;
    ToolBarLabel: TLabel;
    btnNext: TSpeedButton;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    BottomToolBar: TToolBar;
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  HeaderFooterwithNavigation: THeaderFooterwithNavigation;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}
{$R *.iPhone4in.fmx IOS}

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TabControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  it: TListViewItem;
begin
  if TabControl1.ActiveTab = TabItem2 then
  begin
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      it := ListView1.Items.Add;
      it.Text := inttostr(i);
      if odd(i) then
        it.Objects.TextObject.PlaceOffset.Y := 0
      else
        it.Objects.TextObject.PlaceOffset.Y := 10;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.TitleActionUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
  begin
    if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> nil then
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := TabControl1.ActiveTab.Text
    else
      TCustomAction(Sender).Text := '';
  end;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem2;
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { This defines the default active tab at runtime }
  TabControl1.First(TTabTransition.None);
end;

procedure THeaderFooterwithNavigation.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = vkHardwareBack) and (TabControl1.TabIndex <> 0) then
  begin
    TabControl1.First;
    Key := 0;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Main form (fmx):

```
object HeaderFooterwithNavigation: THeaderFooterwithNavigation
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'HeaderFooter'
  ClientHeight = 567
  ClientWidth = 384
  FormFactor.Width = 1440
  FormFactor.Height = 900
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object TopToolBar: TToolBar
    Anchors = []
    Size.Width = 384.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object ToolBarLabel: TLabel
      Action = TitleAction
      Align = Contents
      Enabled = True
      Size.Width = 384.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'toollabel'
      TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    end
    object btnBack: TSpeedButton
      Action = PreviousTabAction1
      Align = MostLeft
      Enabled = True
      ImageIndex = -1
      Size.Width = 65.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'backtoolbutton'
    end
    object btnNext: TSpeedButton
      Action = NextTabAction1
      Align = MostRight
      Enabled = True
      ImageIndex = -1
      Position.X = 340.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 44.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'nexttoolbutton'
      OnClick = btnNextClick
    end
  end
  object TabControl1: TTabControl
    Align = Client
    FullSize = True
    Size.Width = 384.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 479.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabHeight = 49.000000000000000000
    TabIndex = 0
    TabOrder = 1
    TabPosition = Top
    OnChange = TabControl1Change
    Sizes = (
      384s
      430s
      384s
      430s)
    object TabItem1: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = True
      Size.Width = 191.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Caption Tab Item #1'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 8.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 8.000000000000000000
    end
    object TabItem2: TTabItem
      CustomIcon = <
        item
        end>
      IsSelected = False
      Size.Width = 191.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 49.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = ''
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Caption Tab Item #2'
      ExplicitSize.cx = 8.000000000000000000
      ExplicitSize.cy = 8.000000000000000000
      object ListView1: TListView
        ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemAppearance'
        ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TListItemShowCheckAppearance'
        HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
        FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
        Align = Client
        Size.Width = 384.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 430.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        TabOrder = 0
      end
    end
  end
  object BottomToolBar: TToolBar
    Align = Bottom
    Anchors = [akLeft]
    Position.Y = 523.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 384.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 44.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    StyleLookup = 'bottomtoolbar'
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Left = 176
    Top = 56
    object TitleAction: TControlAction
      Category = 'Tab'
      Text = 'TitleAction'
      OnUpdate = TitleActionUpdate
    end
    object PreviousTabAction1: TPreviousTabAction
      Category = 'Tab'
      TabControl = TabControl1
      ShortCut = 137
    end
    object NextTabAction1: TNextTabAction
      Category = 'Tab'
      TabControl = TabControl1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would be nice if you create a *complete* application as you explain and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68090191/edit) your question with both *.pas* and *.fmx* files so that we have just to copy/paste to test your issue. I would call that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I thought it might be less clicks to create the example from the Delphi templates, but you are right. That even might give a different result. Done as recommended.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had not noticed that. @TomBrunberg fix is correct. Forget about my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using styles in your project, insert a call to:

```
ListView1.ApplyStyleLookup;
```

in the forms `OnCreate` event,

(You don't need it if you later use styles, but it doesn't do any harm either)

After the very first time click on `Next`: All even numbers are offset according to the code.

[image]